# JPA : Map two tables from different services

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables User and Roles now i want to map these table with @OneToMany relationship.
but User entity is present in UserService and Role entity in AuthorizationService.
now i want to create one more table user_roles to map these entities in AuthorizationService.

please help!! how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: What is `AuthorizationService`? is it a repository?